# Simulate a click event on FeatureLayer in ESRI JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When my app changes context (user clicks on a tab) I want to programmatically "Select" the first of 6 points in my Feature Layer so I get the blue box around the point and activate the info window.

I looked around the API Docs and found the [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html)'s [selectFeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#selectfeatures) method.  This method takes a Query object, and a selection method (I'm creating a new selection so I'll use SELECTION_NEW).  The function returns a promise, but do I really need any kind of callback? I'm just trying to select a feature.

**Here is the definition of my feature layer:**

```
var projectsAGOL = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/QVENGdaPbd4LUkLV/arcgis/rest/services/rioLocoSites/FeatureServer/0",{ 
    infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
    visible: true,
    outFields: ["*"]
});
```

**Click handler for the Tab:**

```
jQuery("#prjMap").click(function(){
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query(); // Create a Query Object
    query.where = "OBJECTID = 0"; // Select the first point from the Feature Layer
    projectsAGOL.selectFeatures(query, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW); // Apply selection
});
```

This code does not produce the desired outcome nor does it produce an error.  Nothing happens.  Am I even using the correct method to make a selection?  I'm more familiar with the Leafletjs mapping library.

**Update:** Provided [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74yrR/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#prjMap").click(function(){
    var projectsAGOL = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/.../FeatureServer/0",{ 
        infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
        visible: true,
        outFields: ["*"]
    });

    var query = new esri.tasks.Query(); // Create a Query Object
    query.where = "FID= 0"; // Select the first point from the Feature Layer
    query.returnGeometry = true;
    query.outFields = ["*"]; // Return all attributes in the FeatureSet

    var selectionSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255,255,0,0.5]));
    featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbol); 
    projectsAGOL.selectFeatures(query,esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to expand upon this Answer, please?  Normally "about a paragraph" is considered as the minimum length for Answers (and Questions).

Comment: @Matej In the QueryTask constructor are you passing in the url of the feature service?

Comment: @Roy: Yes, feature service or dynamic map service url

Comment: @Matej I'm still not able to make the selection.  Perhaps you could take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74yrR/)?

Comment: @Roy: Sorry, I might have confused you: 
featureSet = queryTask.execute(query); returns a deferred object. To get the feature itself, use:
when(featureSet , function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
The "result" object represents a returned feature set from the query .

Comment: @Matej Thanks -- that cleared some things up.  I'm able to access the first point in the callback functions of the `queryTask.execute()` method.  I'm still a bit confused how to actually activate the selection.  See updated code above.

Comment: @Roy: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what would you like to accomplish. Since you are using a feature layer, you don't even need to perform a query - data of the feature layer gets to the browser when the layer is loaded. I guess, you just need to fire map click event when the user clicks the tab.

Comment: @Matej Yes -- I'm trying to fire a click event on the map that would select a point from my feature layer.  It will be a visual indication that the application state has changed.  I thought the FeatureLayer.selectFeatures() method would do the trick, which is why I brought in a query to begin with.  If this is all wrong please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Roy: I don't see the point of simulating a map click event if you want to highlight the first couple of features. Please see the updated answer above.

Comment: That's almost identical to what I had from the start.  Just rolled back my original post.  I'm not sure how the outFields or spatialRelationship are relevant here, but I tried what you have.  Unfortunately no selection is made, and no error is presented in the console.

Comment: To see the selected features, you have to set the selection symbol. See the updated answer.